# Best way to mask an image in HTML5

Tags: html, canvas, css, mask

I was wondering what is the best way to mask images in HTML 5 ?

In fact I would like to display circle thumbnails in a gallery without bothering my client with  the preparation of the circular pictures...

So I have, in my opinion, two options : [Canvas masking](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/html5/create-vector-masks-using-the-html5-canvas/) or [old fashioned way](http://www.cssbakery.com/2009/06/background-image.html)

Do you have others ideas ? Best practices ?

Thanks

Comment: did my answer help u . if it did do vote me as the right answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you could use

- the *old fashioned way* - by using a transparent png on top of the desired element
- the css3 `border-radius` of the image set to half of it's dimensions (so that the border defines a circle)
- the css3 `mask` and `mask-clip` properties (here's a nice demo : http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/)
- canvas to do the masking
- svg circles with the image as background-pattern

The choice depends on the targeted browsers and the time you want to invest.
For a fully cross-browser result, I recommend the *old fashioned way*, but if you want more shapes (maybe dynamic ones) or more than just image masking, you could try svg or canvas.

Comment: The CSS3 Masking is WebKit only.

Comment: Of course I would like a cross-browser viable result.. II will animate the mask and the size of the circle after all so I think using css3 border-radius is the most appropriate technique, don't you think ?

Comment: @gion_13 Nice summary of options, but this could be a great answer if you included details (e.g. had a link or code showing how to do each, such as masking a `drawImage` using the `globalCompositeOperation`

Answer (score 3):

```
  -circle {
        -webkit-border-radius: 61px;
        -moz-border-radius: 61px;
        border-radius: 61px;
        border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
        width:122px;
        height:122px;
   }
```

see this

check this http://jsfiddle.net/WQSLa/1/

**EDIT**

u can also try this http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/WQSLa/3 as suggested by albert

Comment: or just drop it on the img instead of the div http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/WQSLa/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method that works best for me:

1. create an SVG of the shape of mask you want.
2. edit the css of the appropriate element and specify the URL of the SVG for the mask

For a 200px circle, your SVG could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="image-mask" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

And your CSS could look like this:

```
#image-mask {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    mask: url('/static/images/avatarmask.svg');
    -webkit-mask-image: url('/static/images/avatarmask.svg');
}
```

And if you want something more in-depth, I found this guide to be very helpful: http://collidercreative.com/how-to-create-css-image-masks-for-the-web-with-svgs/.

Comment: with regards to the example you provided, is the css supposed to be applied to the image? ie:`<img src="/images/myimage.jpg" id="image-mask">`.

Answer (score 0):

To update the answer, try `clip-path` (see [this css-tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/)).

[caniuse](https://caniuse.com) shows over 80% support now, if you use the `-webkit-` prefix as well. So this is working for me (IE/Edge, though, may be limiting factors):

```
clip-path: circle(125px at center);
-webkit-clip-path: circle(125px at center);
```