# How to give my javascript ball a rolling animation when it moves?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have the following HTML code:

`<img src="game_files/ball.png" id="ball" />` 
It's a div containing an image of a ball
(top view of a ball)

This ball I can move with my arrow keys and some javacript to go up, left, right, down, etc etc. I do this with this code:

```
var ball = function  () {
    var inited = false,
        el,
        xcheck = 50,
        x = 50,
        ycheck = 50,
        y = 50,
        xspeed = 0,
        yspeed = 0,
        power = 0.4,
        friction = 0.99,
        xwind = 0,
        ywind = 0,
        dead = true,
        timer = function(keys) {
            if (dead === true) {
                return;
            }
            if (keys[38] === true) {
                yspeed += power;
            }
            if (keys[40] === true) {
                yspeed -= power;
            }
            if (keys[37] === true) {
                xspeed += power;
            }
            if (keys[39] === true) {
                xspeed -= power;
            }
            xspeed = xspeed * friction - xwind;
            yspeed = yspeed * friction - ywind;
            if (Math.abs(xspeed) < 0.004) {
                xspeed = 0;
            }
            if (Math.abs(xspeed) < 0.004) {
                xspeed = 0;
            }
            x -= xspeed;
            y -= yspeed;
            plane.move(x,y);
        };
    return {
        init: function() {
            if (inited != true) {
                inited = true;
                el = document.getElementById('ball');
                roller.register(timer, 'time');
            }
        }
    };
}();
```

This all works, but the ball has no rolling animation! The image just slides to the left or right How can I add this? I found this tutorial: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/06/10/creation-of-realistic-spheres-in-flash-with-textures-and-masking/ which I thought could help me out.

Unfortunately, this is for a flash ball (I was hoping this would apply in some sort to JS too). This tutorial shows exactly what I want: a ball with rolling animation (see the tutorial page near the end of the tutorial the ball with the leopard skin, just below: Lines 26-37: If the position of the texture relatively to the ball...).

How can I apply this to my JS ball? Any thoughts?

Kind regards and a happy new year

ps I use/load jquery as well

--EDIT--------

Created a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/dhUw5/

1- open the fiddle

2- click the 1

3- use the arrow keys to move the ball around, stay on the green field!

4- see, no rolling effect

Comment: For something like this, better attach a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: you could also use the css3-rotation property and animate it

Comment: Added a fiddle see below the --EDIT---

Comment: Is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wTz9j/show/) what you're looking for?

Comment: Dunno, I just see a blue block and cant click anything

Comment: @Maurice What browser are you using?

Comment: @Maurice Sorry, I was using `console.clear` to debug in FF, and that isn't present in other browsers. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/BahnU/show/) should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have the same effect as in the Flash example you linked you just have to add a background to the element and move that accordingly.

I replaced your img element with a span and gave it the background-image via CSS and a border-radius to make it round.
In your plane.move function I added the following line:

```
document.getElementById('ball').style.backgroundPosition = x + 'px ' + y +'px';
```

Voilá, same effect as in the Flash example: http://jsfiddle.net/dhUw5/1/

Comment: OMG sooo easy!! Thanks a lot! ps. is a shadow and "glimmer" like in the last example in the tutorial also possible?

Comment: Yes. Just position an element (preferably a pseudo-element) over the span and give it the "glimmer" background.

Comment: The same as with glimmer. Although you could be able to create something with box-shadow.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably use HTML5 canvas. You would clip part of the image used as the ball's surface using [`drawImage`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp) and then [mask it to get a circle shape](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-vector-masks-using-the-html5-canvas). Then you can animate it by redrawing the canvas, with the clipping position (sx, sy) altered in a similar way to the flash example you linked to. (Following is not tested; make a jsfiddle with your original code if you want to try it.)

```
// ... when the user moves
this.sy += yspeed;
this.sx += xspeed;
if (this.sx > textureSize) {
    this.sx -= textureSize;
}
else if (this.sx < 0) {
    this.sx += textureSize;
}
if (this.sy > textureSize) {
    this.sy -= textureSize;
}
else if (this.sy < 0) {
    this.sy += textureSize;
}

// ... redraw the ball once every frame
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight); // clear the canvas
context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(this.x, this.y, ballRadius, Math.PI * 2, false);
context.clip();    
context.drawImage(ballImage, this.sx, this.sy, 
                  ballDiameter, ballDiameter, 
                  this.x, this.y,
                  ballDiameter, ballDiameter);      // redraw the ball      
context.restore();
```

Alternatively you could use a div with the texture as a background image, and mask it to make a circle using CSS3 or by overlaying another image (see [Best way to mask an image in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337570/best-way-to-mask-an-image-in-html5)). Then you would change the coordinates of the background image (texture) using

`ballElement.style.backgroundPosition = this.sx + 'px ' + this.sy + 'px';`

Comment: Thanks but had no luck. Added a fiddle (see bottom original post), hope this helps!

Comment: It's almost a year and I thought about trying your solution, but still cannot get it to work. Could you edit my fiddle? I would really like to know how this would work with canvas!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy if you use CSS transforms. In this example the speed of rotation is determined according to the scalar value of the speed the ball is currently traveling at:

```
    var increment = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xspeed, 2) + Math.pow(yspeed, 2)));
    if (!isNaN(increment)) {
        currangle = currangle + ((xspeed < 0 ? 1 : -1) * increment);
    }

    $('#ball').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + currangle + 'deg)'
    });

    $('#ball').css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + currangle + 'deg)'
    });
```

This code goes in the `move` method in `plane`. Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/BahnU/show/

Comment: Nice, although this rotates rather than scrolling the background.

Comment: @Stuart Yeah I realised I'd misunderstood the question once I saw the accepted answer.