# jQuery Crop a Circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, gd

Is there a script in jQuery/javascript to select a circle on a image and give the coordinates to a script ( php / gd ) to crop/blur that image ?

Thanks

Comment: probably could do it with a `<canvas>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if there is any for circles, but you could use this http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ to select a rectangle, you could then calculate the circle from the center of that rectangle and apply the crop of blur you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337570/best-way-to-mask-an-image-in-html5) on masking images to form circles. Basically, there are a number of options, and I quote:

> - the *old fashioned way* - by using a transparent png on top of the desired element
> - the css3 `border-radius` of the image set to half of it's dimensions (so that the border defines a circle)
> - the css3 `mask` and `mask-clip` properties (here's a nice demo : http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/)
> - canvas to do the masking
> - svg circles with the image as background-pattern

Comment: as i said i want to blur that circle not generate a circle for that image. For example let's say that we have a photo of a person and i want to blur that person's face and a label from a product from that photo