# Circle mask on html

Tags: html, dictionary, mask, geometry

I'd like to circle mask the following:

See on map

http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/sinan.map-l9wtmm6y.html#15/41.00996511838453/28.974809646606428'>

I checked the previous topics but since I am very new to html I couldn't find the answer.

appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how you want to go about it, the simplest and unfortunately the least robust route would be to create a large .png with the alpha in the center transparent.

There are also ways to do it using html5 canvas, CSS3, etc. but I think the more important question is what you are trying to do with it before you decide the route to take. (do you need it to resize, do you need it to change colors, etc.) Here is a link to another stack overflow post that may get you on your way.

[Best way to mask an image in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337570/best-way-to-mask-an-image-in-html5)