# HTML/CSS Image with gradient on frames to blend it with background

Tags: html, css

Hi I can't exactly find a name for it but what I am trying to accomplish is to instert an image and blend it with background using CSS gradient(for example from full white to transparent) to on frames. I used spray in photoshop to better explain. Can someone send me some tutorials or help me find a name for the action I am trying to do so I can find some tutorials? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is make this effect with Photoshop and save as `.png` with transparent background instead white color of frame. Then you will be able to see background color in your website

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely a few approaches you can take!
What you're looking for is:

> **"image masking"**

There's [a great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337570/best-way-to-mask-an-image-in-html5) that outlines a few of the approaches.

*Note: the question I've linked to has link-rot, but the answer is still good.*